# Converting symbology to representation in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

I need to convert my feature symbology to representation because I want to move them (they are overlapping). In ArcMap, there was a function called "Convert Symbology to representation..." but I can't find it in ArcGIS Pro. Is there any other way to move my symbology? I found, that I can edit representation points in the Edit tab, but that's accessible only in the map view (symbology proportion is not displayed as in the layout view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. Arrange everything in the layout view, then switch to the map view. Next, "Set reference scale" at desired scale and then you can zoom in and in the Edit tab, move items (after creating a duplicate layer to preserve original data). Probably not the best solution but it works.